# Python Rate Limit class based view Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful

I'm following this example:

http://flask-limiter.readthedocs.org/en/stable/#ratelimit-string

```
app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(app, key_func=get_remote_address)

class MyView(flask.views.MethodView):
    decorators = [limiter.limit("10/second")]
    def get(self):
        return "get"

    def put(self):
        return "put"
```

My problem is that in example, the application, limiter and classes are defined in the same file  in my case the application and limiter are defined in the same file but my classes live in a separate file.

If I import either limiter or app my Flask app doesn't start because circular [dependencies](http://pastebin.com/raw/2yArEjyZ). How can fix this, what is the recommended way? I want to apply limiter to specific endpoints.
I tried `from flask import current_app`in order to initialize limiter but this function was not take it as a valid parameter. Any recommendations?

**File information:**

- app.py
- api_main.py

Under app.py I have defined my resources:

```
api_app = Flask(__name__)  # Flask Application
api_app.config.from_pyfile("../../../conf/settings.py")  # Flask configuration

imbue_api = restful.Api(api_app)  # Define API
limiter = Limiter(api_app, key_func=get_remote_address, global_limits=["10 per second"])

imbue_api.add_resource(ApiBase, settings.BASE_API_URL)
```

In api_main.py I have defined all my classes:

```
class ApiBase(Resource):
    @authenticator.requires_auth
    def get(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        try:
            # =========================================================
            # GET API
            # =========================================================
            log.info(request.remote_addr + ' ' + request.__repr__())
            if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
                # =========================================================
                # Send API version information
                # =========================================================
                log.info('api() | GET | Version' + settings.api_version)
                response = json.dumps('version: ' + settings.api_version)
                resp = Response(response, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
                return resp

        except KeyError:
            response = json.dumps('Invalid type headers. Use application/json')
            resp = Response(response, status=415, mimetype='application/json')
            return resp

        except Exception, exception:
            log.exception(exception.__repr__())
            response = json.dumps('Internal Server Error')
            resp = Response(response, status=500, mimetype='application/json')
            return resp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Resource.method_decorators`

[https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/**init**.py#L574](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L574)

It is applied for each request. You can override it in your view class:

```
@property
def method_decorators(self):
    # get some limiter bound to the `g` context
    # maybe you prefer to get it from `current_app`
    return g.limiter
```

If you prefer, you can append the limiter to the existing `method_decorators` before adding the resource to your restful API.

```
ApiBase.method_decorators.append(limiter)
imbue_api.add_resource(ApiBase, settings.BASE_API_URL)
```