# Limiter in Class based Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

From here:
[Python Rate Limit class based view Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859660/python-rate-limit-class-based-view-flask)
I implemented solution:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address

limiter = Limiter(api_app, key_func=get_remote_address, global_limits=[settings.api_global_limits])
Status.method_decorators.append(limiter)
gonzo_api.add_resource(Status, '/api/1.0/status')
```

My `Status` class:

```
class Status(Resource):
    """Verifies API status."""

    @authenticator.db_authentication
    def get(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        try:
            log.info('%s %r' % (request.remote_addr, request))
            log.info('api() | GET | Received request for Status')
            response = json.dumps('Status: GET. Hola %s!' % g.user.username)
            return Response(response, status=200, mimetype=settings.api_mime_type)
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            log.exception(e)
            response = json.dumps(errors.API_ERROR)
            return Response(response, status=500, mimetype=settings.api_mime_type)
```

Relevant code:

[https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/**init**.py#L574](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L574)

Error 1:

```
[2017-11-18 23:49:35 -0800] [95972] [DEBUG] GET /api/1.0/status
[2017-11-18 23:49:35,332] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/1.0/status [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 585, in dispatch_request
    meth = decorator(meth)
TypeError: 'Limiter' object is not callable
```

If I add the following code to `Status` class it fails:

```
@property
def method_decorators(self):
    # get some limiter bound to the `g` context
    return g.limiter
```

Error 2:
Error seems to be related to `Status.method_decorators.append` as `method_decorators` is a [], when we call it we are calling the getter, not the setter.

```
[2017-11-18 23:55:00 -0800] [3228] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzo/api/version1_0/gonzo_api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from application.app import api_app
  File "/Users/spicyramen/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/gonzo/api/version1_0/application/app.py", line 74, in <module>
    Status.method_decorators.append(limiter)
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#flask_limiter.Limiter.limit) the method you need for decorating is `limit` so perhaps doing something like this:

```
Status.method_decorators.append(limiter.limit('50 per hour'))
```

rate limit string formats are found [here](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#ratelimit-string)